# Widgets in the list share their state

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Problem summary**

- I have a `List<Card> cards` consisting of my statefull widget `Card`.
- `child: cards[cardIndex]` displays a Card widget based on the `int cardIndex`. Meaning, that whenever the `cardIndex` increases by 1, the `Card` widget displayed changes to a next one int the `cards` list.

Everything works as expected, except that the next displayed widget from the list inherits State of the previous widget.

In the following visual example whenever a button "forward" is pressed, a next widget from the list is displayed (each widget has different colour). Each of the widgets have a counter which increases when the widget is pressed. However, it's state is inherited by the next widget! Meaning, that the next displayed widget will display count inherited from the previous widget - [image: visual illustration of the problem]

**Minimal reproducible example**

The `Card` class contains a `int counter` which determines what number is being displayed.

```
class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  Card({
    this.color = Colors.blue,
  });

  @override
  _CardState createState() => _CardState();
}

class _CardState extends State<Card> {

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 450,
      width: 300,
      color: widget.color,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            counter++;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          counter.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 40.0,
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The page only contains a `Column` with a current `Card` and a `TextButton` to increase the `int cardIndex` (determining the current `Card` being displayed)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home:App()));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  List<Card> cards = [
    Card(color: Colors.blue),
    Card(color: Colors.purple),
    Card(color: Colors.red),
    Card(color: Colors.yellow),
    Card(color: Colors.green),
  ];

  int cardIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        cards[cardIndex],
        TextButton(
          child: Text("forward"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if(cardIndex < cards.length - 1) {
                cardIndex++;
              } else {
                cardIndex = 0;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

First, I though the issue is with my project. But as I started making minimal reproducible example, I realised, that the problem still persists.
I might possibly be able to overcome this issue by resetting it's state whenever a new widget is displayed. However, I would rather find a proper solution. And ultimatelly, I would like to understand why is this happening in the first place.

Comment: *"Everything works as expected, except that the next displayed widget from the list inherits State of the previous widget."* - add `_CardState() { print('_CardState constructor'); }` to your code and you will see why it happens

Comment: @pskink interesting, so the constructor is only called once. Maybe I am far reaching, however is changing the index handled internally the same way as changing widget argument; where the constructor is not called? Or is there totally different reason behind it?

Comment: what you mean by "changing widget argument; where the constructor is not called" - if you call `Text('foo')` and then after some `setState(...)` you call `Text('bar')` to change the widget argument then `Text` widget constructor is called twice

Comment: I am probably mixing up terms here as I am new to Dart, but here is visual representation of what I meant - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfAZQ1Hq8wmd7_rcbko2i-ltSO1ATgGU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: basically you should keep the counters in some array, not in `State` class - the question: how would you access `State`s objects in order to do something with those counters? for excample try: `Card({
this.color = Colors.blue,
}) : super(key: UniqueKey());` - what next?

Comment: There are always the `GlobalKey()`s; `int counter = _cardState.currentState.counter;` so accessing the `State`s object is not an issue. Altough I am not sure if that is a best practice. I should definitelly read-up on state management in Flutter!

Comment: agree, it is not a best practice... check `TextField`, `Slider`, `Checkbox`, `Radio` - they do not store any 'state' values internally - all has to be provided by you (by means of `cvontroller: ...`, `value: ...` etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first of all I am not sure why your widget act like that, your code seems okay to me. I think it might be related to the fact that you are instantiating a list of `Card` widgets which might be all refeering to the same state.

While I don't have an explanation about this I've found a workaround to make your app work without too much modification.

Basically instead of having a `Card` widget for each of your color you will have only one using a `CardData` as its parameter to get the `color` and `counter` values.

```dart
/// Class used to keep your data
class CardData {
  final Color color;
  int counter = 0;

  CardData(this.color);
}

// ....

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  /// List of CardData instead of Card widget
  final _data = <CardData>[
    CardData(Colors.blue),
    CardData(Colors.purple),
    CardData(Colors.red),
    CardData(Colors.yellow),
    CardData(Colors.green),
  ];

  int cardIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // Refer to only one Card widget with variable CardData
        Card(_data[cardIndex]),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("forward"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (cardIndex < _data.length - 1) {
                cardIndex++;
              } else {
                cardIndex = 0;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// New Card Widget
class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  final CardData data;
  
  Card(this.data);

  @override
  State<Card> createState() => _CardState();
}

class _CardState extends State<Card> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 450,
      width: 300,
      color: widget.data.color,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => widget.data.counter++),
        child: Text(
          widget.data.counter.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 40.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[You can try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b46361b8df99296cc908c69b77e0fddb)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Your approach works on a small scale but becomes problematic when applied to larger projects; where statefull widget is composed of other statefull widgets etc. (You would have to keep track and pass on data to all of them...). I did some digging and found out, that the widget's state is not created on initialization, but rather when it's being drawn. To overcome this, I assigned a key at initialization 'Card(color: Colors.red, key: GlobalKey())' which fixed the issue. However, using this the state of the widget is lost when the index moves. Therefore, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: You could use an architecture like BLoC to pass data between your widgets it fix lots of state management issues.